# Matlab, I have an error in matlab if- else script. I can not save it and run

Tags: matlab

I am new in matlab and trying a new script . It is working when I click "Run and Advance" button, but when I "save", then "run", it gives this error:

" if
↑
Error: Invalid expression. Check for missing or extra characters."

My code is:

```
x=input("Sayı: ");
if x<45 
fprintf("Küçük ve :%d", x);
elseif x<55 
fprintf("Büyük ve %d", x);
else
fprintf("Baya büyük");
end;
```

What should I do ?

Edit: I checked code again, but in matlab it is not working. So as you say, I think the problem is about version of matlab or smt. else. Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 1):

```
x=input("Sayı: ");
if x<45 
fprintf("Küçük ve :%d", x)
elseif x<55 
fprintf("Büyük ve %d", x)
else
fprintf("Baya büyük")
end
```

No need for the `;` after the `end` or the `fprintf` statements.

Comment: This doesn't really solve OP's problem. In fact, having a semicolon at `end` or `fprintf()` doesn't change anything, and to be fair OP's initial code doesn't really have any issue...

Comment: @MatteoV That's fair enough - I couldn't test this as the machine which I use Matlab on was off. This was my best guess as I couldn't see any other problems. Perhaps OP can help out by providing some more details.